# Can't start appium inspector session: exited with code 255

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, appium

I am trying to start an appium inspector session, however I keep having problems with apkanalyzer.bat, now I received the following message:

```
Using 'apkanalyzer.bat' from 'C:\Users\ayla_\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\apkanalyzer.bat'
[ADB] Starting 'C:\Users\ayla_\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\apkanalyzer.bat' with args ["-h","manifest","print","C:\\Users\\ayla_\\Documents\\Documentos_Ayla\\Treinamentos\\Automacao Mobile\\File Manager by Astro File Browser_v7.4.0_apkpure.com.apk"]
[ADB] Using the alternative activity name detection method because of: Command 'C\:\\Users\\ayla_\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools\\bin\\apkanalyzer.bat -h manifest print 'C:\\Users\\ayla_\\Documents\\Documentos_Ayla\\Treinamentos\\Automacao Mobile\\File Manager by Astro File Browser_v7.4.0_apkpure.com.apk'' exited with code 255
[ADB] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\ayla_\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1569549028506 (22:50:28 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Command 'java -jar C\:\\Users\\ayla_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\appium_apk_tools.jar printLaunchActivity 'C:\\Users\\ayla_\\Documents\\Documentos_Ayla\\Treinamentos\\Automacao Mobile\\File Manager by Astro File Browser_v7.4.0_apkpure.com.apk' C\:\\Users\\ayla_\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\com.metago.astro' exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x7f060046 color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default, config=[DEFAULT]
```

If someone knows the solution to this problem, please share with me.

Comment: Could you post the desired capabilities you are using to start the Appium session? Including the .apk file or appPackage / appActivity you are using

Comment: Yes, of course:
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capability.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 2 API 27");
  capability.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
  capability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");


I search and maybe the problem is that I need to input those capabilities, but I dont know where to find those information:
  capability.setCapability("appPackage", "");
  capability.setCapability("appActivity", "");

Comment: Have you set the `app` or `appPackage` capabilities? Unless you are starting a browser session, you need specify an .apk file in your desired capabilities. If you don’t have an .apk file you are passing in, I can point you in the right direction on how to get that.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I tried to set the appPackage capability, but I couldn't find that information in my apk file, do you know how to find it? I tried some command lines on cmd, however it didn't work :(

Comment: I would follow this guide: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

Comment: Thanks a lot Cristine, my problem was solved!! Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Hi, I have issue with apkanalyzer.bat. Could you please at least post your solution as answer for the comunity? Thanks.